# DataFrameで各行毎に処理をした結果を1つのリストにまとめる方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas, numpy

DataFrameで各行毎に処理をした結果を1つのリストにまとめたいです。
下記のように書くことはできたのですが、可読性向上のために、`myfunc`内で関数外のリストに要素を追加しているのをやめて、別の方法で書くことはできないでしょうか？
`apply`以外の方法でも構わないのですが、`iterrows`は使わずに書きたいです。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["Yamada", ["a", "b", "c"]],
        ["Tanaka", ["d", "a", "f"]],
        ["Suzuki", ["g", "h", "i"]],
    ],
    columns=["name", "tags"],
)

# 結果のリスト
# myfunc関数内から関数外の変数を更新しているのをやめたい
names = []
first_tags = []


def myfunc(row):
    names.append(row["name"])
    first_tags.append(row["tags"][0])


df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)

print(names)  # ['Yamada', 'Tanaka', 'Suzuki']
print(first_tags)  # ['a', 'd', 'g']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

関数外の変数に直接アクセスせず、変数のスコープを絞りたいという意図であれば[pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)に`args`を渡すことで対応可能です。
※下記サンプルコードの`myfunc`をご参照ください。

関数からは絶対にリストへアクセスせず、各行のデータのみ扱うよう疎結合にしたいならば、関数では単純にSeriesを返しておき、関数外でリスト化する方法もあります。
※下記サンプルコードの`my_first_tags`をご参照ください。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["Yamada", ["a", "b", "c"]],
        ["Tanaka", ["d", "a", "f"]],
        ["Suzuki", ["g", "h", "i"]],
    ],
    columns=["name", "tags"],
)

# 結果のリスト
# myfunc関数内から関数外の変数を更新しているのをやめたい
names = []
first_tags = []

def myfunc(row, ns, fts):
    ns.append(row["name"])
    fts.append(row["tags"][0])

df.apply(myfunc, axis=1, args=(names, first_tags))

print(names)  # ['Yamada', 'Tanaka', 'Suzuki']
print(first_tags)  # ['a', 'd', 'g']

def my_first_tags(row):
    return row["tags"][0]

first_tags = df.apply(my_first_tags, axis=1).values.tolist()
print(first_tags)  # ['a', 'd', 'g']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
names = df['name'].to_list()
first_tags = df['tags'].str[0].to_list()
print(names)
print(first_tags)

#
['Yamada', 'Tanaka', 'Suzuki']
['a', 'd', 'g']
```